# How thread unsuspending works?

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, jvm

My primary background is JVM and I have a high-level understanding of OS threads. I know that once I do some sort of IO current thread gets suspended and is activated once the action is complete. What I don't know is how the system knows when to activate a given thread. Here is couple of questions to make answering easier:

1. What thread suspension reasons are possible? I know thread can wait network packet or for user input via stdin or for data from hard disk. Is there sth more? Is there unified API for those on the system level? How does waiting for other threads fits into this?
2. How the system knows that given thread is ready to be activated? Is it push based or pull based mechanism?
3. How synchronous vs asynchronous apis fits into this? I know that jdbc for example is synchronous by nature and Apache async http client is asynchronous. I also know that wrapping some operation into separate thread doesn't make it truly asynchronous. Do you need to integrate with some specific system apis to make things truly async?

Let's assume we are talking only about Linux.
It feels like I'm missing some big amount of knowledge about system level programming. I would like to understand what happens when I am doing blocking operation.

Comment: Too many questions at once. Some of them are not even related, except being somehow connected to threads.

Comment: Anything will be helpful. I need at least something to deepen the understanding. Also, these are just helper questions, answer to the main one would be enough, if answering all of them is to hard

Comment: What is the main question?

Comment: "How thread unsuspending works?" anything close to answering this would be helpful.

Comment: But where should answering such a broad question start? If you already have “a high-level understanding of OS threads”, you should already know the answer. Unless you want to dig deep into the implementation. Then, which operation system’s implementation do you want to analyze?

Comment: Linux or posix if it is standardized, as I mentioned at the end of the post :)

Comment: 'Interrupts' is, I think, what you are searching for.  Google 'Interrupts in operating systems'.  Hardware interrupts to drivers provide the 'push' functionality needed to make a waiting thread ready/running when the I/O operation that it requested is completed.